# Получить домен из url вида http://test.google.ru/

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо получить домен из `url` вида http://test.google.ru/ (нужно получить google.ru) при этом возможен и такой вариант, что будет http://google.ru/ (нужно получить google.ru) или http://test.www.google.ru/  (нужно получить google.ru)и даже такой http://test.privet.www.google.ru.com/ (нужно получить google.ru.com). И вообще не обязательно google домен будет, а может быть и yandex и vasya и вообще какой угодно.

Наработки:

```
parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

В общем я говорю о том, что мне нужно получить главное доменное имя с доменной зоной. Доменные зоны бывают первого уровня и второго: .ru и .ru.com, .com и .com.am и так далее.

Т.е., так скажем, в регулярке должно быть что-то типа `[.*\\.]{0,}(A-Za-z-А-Я-а-я][\\.]{1,2})` , где то, что в скобках, должно парситься. Т.е. должна парситься та информация, которая находится перед последними одной или двумя точками, а также то, что после этой информации - доменная зона, но до если ранее встречались точки, то информация перед ними не парсится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$txt = 'Необходимо получить домен из url вида http://test.google.ru/ (нужно получить google.ru) при этом возможен и такой вариант, что будет http://google.ru/';
$pattern = '#(?<=\.|/|\s)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,61}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(?=\s|/)#i';

preg_match_all($pattern,$txt,$matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

[Посмотреть](http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/z9n-1dv), что получается.

Comment: Это плохое решение, т.к. оно режет не правильно, если брать к примеру домены подобного характера test.22i.in.net то мы в результате получим in.net хотя основной домен 22i.in.net